# Testing for member function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Assume the following rather simple class:

```c
struct A {
    bool toBool() const { return true; }
    template<typename T> T to() const { return T();}
};
```

Now, I wish to test for the existence of `toBool`:

```c
template<typename From, typename To>
class has_toBool_func
{
    typedef char (&Two)[2];
    template<typename F, bool (F::*)() const> struct helper {};
    template<typename F> static char test(helper<F, &F::toBool>*);
    template<typename F> static Two test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<From>(0)) == sizeof(char));
};
```

is defined and used:

```c
::std::cout << "int: " << has_toBool_func<int, bool>::value
    << ", A: " << has_toBool_func<A, bool>::value << ::std::endl;
```

And yields just the expected output "int: 0, A: 1".

Trying the same thing for the function template:

```c
class has_to_func
{
    typedef char (&Two)[2];
    template<typename F, To (F::*)() const> struct helper {};
    template<typename F> static char test(helper<F, &F::to<To> >*);
    template<typename F> static Two test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<From>(0)) == sizeof(char));
};

::std::cout << "int: " << has_to_func<int, bool>::value
    << ", A: " << has_to_func<A, bool>::value << ::std::endl;
```

yields not the expected output "int: 0, A: 1", but rather a compilation error.

**Why is this happening?** And of course: How can I fix it?

### MSVC 2012

gives a warning

```c
warning C4346: 'F::to' : dependent name is not a type  
      prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type  
      see reference to class template instantiation 'xtd::has_to_func<From,To>' being compiled
```

which is useless, since the dependent name is in fact not a type and an error

```c
error C2998: 'char test' : cannot be a template definition
```

which is also not really helpful...

### ICC 13.0

gives first the error

```c
error : type name is not allowed  
        template<typename F> static char test(helper<F, &F::to<To>() >*);
```

(The `<To>` is marked)

which describes the problem, but still leaves me completely in the dark as to why this happens and another error

```c
error : expected a ")"  
        template<typename F> static char test(helper<F, &F::to<To>() >*);
```

(the last `>` is marked)

which I am pretty sure is complete bollocks and only shown because the compiler got confused.

Comment: this looks like you want to evaluate a compile time assert at runtime ...

Comment: Your `to()` function is missing a return type:  `template<typename T> to() const { return T();}`

Comment: @Alex Not at all, I just want a minimal test case by outputting the compile time computation to the standard output. When all is said and done it is supposed to be used to allow compile time decisions based on whether .to<T> is supported

Comment: @juanchopanza That is what I get for typing it instead of copy-pasting it from my source file ;)

Comment: @dionadar when creating complex posts, what I do sometimes is create a text file in an editor with the 4-space indent and `/*` and `*/` before and after each code block (in the code portion).  This results in a pile of text that is both a valid C++ program, and a valid SO post.  Then get that to compile using an online compiler (or fail in the expected way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the parentheses when passing `&F::to<To>` as a template argument to `helper`, and you should use the `template` disambiguator to tell the compiler that:

- `to` should be interpreted as the name of a template;
- the subsequent angular brackets should delimit template arguments
  rather than being interpreted as *less-than* and *greater-than*:

```
template<typename F> static char test(helper<F, &F::template to<To> >*);
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After adding `T` as the return type of `A::to<>()`, this seems to works for me (tested on GCC 4.7.2). Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/Ccjzu5).

Comment: The parentheses where in fact a remainder from a (stupid and desperate) attempt that changed nothing at all.